# What is the difference between showpress and a longpress in android?

Tags: android

```
 @Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    buckysmessage.setText("onShowPress");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    buckysmessage.setText("onSingleTapUp");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    buckysmessage.setText(" onScroll");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    buckysmessage.setText("onLongPress");
}
```

Basically I do not know what constitutes a long press vs. a show press in android.As you can see I was overiding the methods from the gesture interface and I was confused to what in which those two gestures are.

Comment: The documentation explains the difference...  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html

Answer (score 0):

The user has performed a down MotionEvent and not performed a move or up yet. This event is commonly used to provide visual feedback to the user to let them know that their action has been recognized i.e. highlight an element.

An example would be the time it takes to mark the text below your tap in whatsapp or almost any application with text.